# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) if function in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do select queries based on the result of a boolean statement. Following is the code:

```
select if((3<0) ,(Select * from tbl_research) ,(Select * from tbl_dept_research))
```

It shows me

> ## 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

error.

Comment: The [IF() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) is not a flow control statement. Perhaps you're confusing it with the [IF statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) but that can only be used in stored programs.

Comment: if you need  a flow control the you should use a procedural language for choose the select you need